# Validate line endings

Tags: windows, git

I was wondering if it's at all possible to have git point at a commit, and then spit back out any files in there that don't follow the specified line ending requirements in `gitattributes` file?

This will be on a Windows box.

Comment: Not clear me what you want to do? checkout a specific commit and on the specific commit do something? or maybe form this point on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of looking I can't find a solution to this.

Instead I looked into the git source code for how it determines what the line endings should be (based on the .gitattributes) and it's pretty basic, so I'll just run with that logic.